# How to listen and generate respones for client in server in java?

Tags: java

This is my server side code in java listening on port 1880 and making http client request from browser/client.java code in localhost which gives connection refused error.I copied that server code from a webpage.I am not sure what exactly this code is doing.

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class ServerHandlingHttpRequest {
   public void start() throws IOException
    {
                InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress(1880);
                System.out.println(addr.getPort());
                System.out.println(addr.getAddress());
                System.out.println(addr.getHostName());
                System.out.println(addr.toString());

                HttpServer server=HttpServer.create(addr,0);
                server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
                server.setExecutor(null);
                server.start();
                System.out.println("Server Listening");
                System.out.println(server.getAddress());
                server.stop(60);
        }
      class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Request Arrived");
        String response = "This is the response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
          ServerHandlingHttpRequest w=new ServerHandlingHttpRequest();
          w.start();
     }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I want to listen client request on port 1880 and generate response to that request.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/LightweightHTTPServer.htm This is the link from where I copied and modified the server side code.

Comment: I don't want to go into threading concept right now.I just want a simple server side code.

Answer (score 0):

That code simply starts listening to the port that you have specified, as an HTTP listener. Which means, any HTTP Request that might come into that port will be intercepted by your program. And when it intercepts, it looks for the context path that you have configured to handle the response to the request.

So, when you run this program, it starts listening at port 1880. When a URL http://localhost:1880/ is hit, it will be intercepted by the handler, MyHandler. The response will be written to the OutputStream which will send back the request back to the client.

One of the problems that I see is that you are stopping the server after printing some statements, while the example that you have refered is not doing so. May be, remove `server.stop(60)` statement and check whether the issue still persists.

Comment: Yes after removing server.stop(60) it works but I want to stop server to listening after 60 seconds.

Comment: What exactly means by this line in code: InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress(1880)?I know there should be two endpoints for communication one at client side(socket address = Client IP address+Client Port) and other at server(socket address = Server IP address + Server Port).So which one socket address is generated by InetSocketAddress?